# making a clickable linux desktop shortcut to execute ant build script

Tags: linux, ant, shortcut-file

In my `ubuntu lucid linux` system,I have some `java` code in `~/dev/java/mycode/src` folder.I have an ant buildfile in `~/dev/java/mycode` folder ,which compiles the java files and make a `jar` and finally execute the jar.I do this in a terminal as follows

```
cd ~/dev/java/mycode
ant -f mybuildfile.xml
```

I wanted to create a desktop shortcut ,clicking on which the above events will occur in a terminal.So I created a `'mylaunchfile'` in `/home/me/dev/java` folder and gave it `chmod +x` .The contents are as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
ant -f /home/me/dev/java/mycode/mybuildfile.xml
```

When I open a terminal ,cd to `/home/me/dev/java` and run

```
>bash mylaunchfile
```

It executes ant properly and the java code is run.

Then ,I created a `desktop launcher` with command as

`bash /home/me/dev/java/mylaunchfile`

.Double Clicking on this shortcut doesn't bring up the terminal or run the bash command or do anything.

What do I need to get this clickable shortcut working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you database before you can launch the command

```
sudo updatedb
```

should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the reply..but that doesn't cause doubleclicking the icon execute the command